# How to use velocity with ant instead of "include" within JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, ant, include, velocity

I used the include tag in a JSP file for a kind of mini template. I put the generalized parts in seperated text files and included them in my special JSPs. This is very slow on loading. Now I want to include this parts via velocity on the build process.

I learned that velocity has a "parse" and "include" command. **But how could I define a ant task for velocity so that these commands are used by velocity to generated my new JSPs?** I don't find any examples for using velocity in such a simple way with ant.

Maybe there is an alternative to velocity.

Thank you very much!

Vivid

Comment: Downvoting without giving a hint?!? :-(

Answer (score 1):

JSP includes are slow on loading only for the first time - they need to be compiled. They should not be slow on the subsequent requests. If it is slow on subsequent requests, then you are most likely using wrong include:
[What's the difference between including files with JSP include directive, JSP include action and using JSP Tag Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580120/whats-the-difference-between-including-files-with-jsp-include-directive-jsp-in)

If you want to speed up the initial access, you should precompile JSPs:
[What is the best way to precompile JSPs using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230037/what-is-the-best-way-to-precompile-jsps-using-ant)

Velocity is a generic templating system but it does not suit your case. Velocity could be used **instead of** JSPs, supports includes and initial loading is way faster than JSP compilation.